# How to set up Scala API docs for IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, homebrew, scaladoc

`Scala` is installed using `homebrew`, and when I create a new Scala project, I use the path `/usr/local/opt/scala/idea` with the proper symlinks

[image: IntelliJ create new Scala project]

IntelliJ detects the compiler and libraries correctly, auto-complete, compilation and running works fine.

The problem is IntelliJ does not detect the Scala API documentation, even though the Javadocs path is correct

[image: Scala API docs path]

The contents of the directories look correct too:

hanxue-mac:idea hanxue$ ls doc/scala-devel-docs/api
index       index.js    package.html
index.html  lib     scala
hanxue-mac:idea hanxue$ ls /usr/local/opt/scala/idea
doc lib src
hanxue-mac:idea hanxue$ ls /usr/local/opt/scala/idea/doc/scala-devel-docs/api
index       index.js    package.html
index.html  lib     scala

This is a screenshot when I select a Scala class and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

[image: Scala documentation not found]

Note that I have the same problem in `IntelliJ Idea 132.719` as well as `IntelliJ Idea 12 CE`. How should I set up the Javadocs path for Scala API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know I am giving this answer repeatedly, *but*... If you set up your project with sbt and sbt-idea (task `gen-idea`), you get a correctly set up scala-library with documentation.

Here is a screenshot of an example project, perhaps you can use this approach manually—it uses a dedicated jar `scala-library-2.10.3-javadoc.jar` instead of pointing to an extracted API folder:

[image]

IDEA seems to have problems with type aliases (e.g. `import collection.immutable.{IndexedSeq => Vec}` means it won't look up the doc of `Vec.empty`), but in general it works as expected:

[image]

(Oops, doesn't paste in doc macros, like `$bfinfo` and `$thatinfo` :)

Comment: Thank you very much @0__ I did not try sbt-idea earlier because I thought ideally all Scala related settings should be set within `IntelliJ` to prevent any complications. 

Is the Javadocs jar file dynamically generated each time sbt-idea is used?

Is it still possible to set up the API Docs path from within IntelliJ?

Comment: The docs are not generated, but they are downloaded from the internet, from where the scala library itself is also grabbed (e.g. http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.scala-lang|scala-library|2.10.3|jar ). If you download the javadoc-jar from this link, you should be able to set up the path from within IntelliJ, just as shown in the first screenshot.